# How to organise promises in for loop and pass argument between functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to implement my first promise in javascript. I have these function. Each one of function must be completed to go to next step:

```
F1 --> get Current User Id
       and save it to var "MyUserID"

F2 --> getUserEvent (example 10 events)
       Go to a for loop for each event
       and for each iteration save value to var "EventId" 

           F3--> Get info for that specific event from facebook
           This function has 2 parameters (MyUserID,EventId)

           F4--> Get image for that specific event
           This function has 1 parameter (EventId)

           f5--> Save info to DB
           Go back to the loop
```

To implement this, I have done the following but I know it is not working. I really appreciate if anyone with experience of promises can just show the prototype for me. I am not sure how to pass arguments between functions:

```
var getMyID = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // Get my id from facebook
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            if (response && !response.error) {
                console.log("response==   "+ JSON.stringify(response));
                retuen(response.id);//MyUserId
            }
        });
    });
};

getMyID.then(function(myID) {
    FB.api('/me/events', function(response) {
        console.log("response==   "+ JSON.stringify(response));    

        for(i=0; i<response.data.length;i++) {

            console.log("eventID=  "+response.data[i].id);
            getEvent(response.data[i].id,myID);
        }
    });

}).catch(function(error) {

    console.log('oh no', error);

}).then(function(eventID,myID) {
     FB.api("/"+ eventID , function (response3) {

            if (response3 && !response3.error) {
                //....
                if(myID == response3.owner.id && diff < 0 )
                {
                    //save to DB -- Another place I need to add promise

                }

            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see the following bugs:

- The promise returned by `getMyID` does not ever get resolved or rejected.
- `getMyID.then` won't work, because `getMyID` is a `Function`, not a `Promise`. Perhaps you mean `getMyID().then(...)`
- The callback that has the call to `/me/events` should return a `Promise` so that it is asynchronous. As it currently is, it will kick off the call to the Facebook API and go to the next `then` handler immediately after.
- Same with the final `then` handler.
- You ought to put the `catch` at the end so it catches all errors.
- Typo where you have `retuen` instead of `return`.

For the sake of DRY, I'd recommend you create a Promise-returning wrapper around the Facebook API. Something like this:

```
function fbAPIRequest(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    FB.api(url, function(response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        resolve(response);
      } else {
        reject(response);
      }
    });
  };
}
```

This will make your code a bit easier:

```
var myUserID;

fbAPIRequest('/me')
  .then(function (response) {
    myUserID = response.id;
    return fbAPIRequest('/me/events');
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    var eventPromises = response.data.map(function (data) {
      return getEvent(data.id, myUserID);
    });
    return Promise.all(eventPromises);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('oh no', error);
  });

function getEvent(eventID, userID) {
  return fbAPIRequest('/' + eventID)
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response.owner.id === userID && diff < 0) {
        return saveToDB(response);
      }
    });
}

function saveToDB(event) {
  return new Promise(...);
}
```

You'll notice that I passed data among callbacks by either returning values (this becomes the value consumed by the next callback in the chain), returning promises that will resolve to values, or utilizing closures (like setting the `myUserID` variable).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure why you used response.data.map? I need to have a foor loop there!

Comment: I assume you want to execute an async task for each event in the array. So I used `map` to convert the array to an array of `Promise` objects, and `Promise.all` to execute them in parallel. Why do you _need_ a for loop?